# How to expose a C++ visual element to QML

Tags: qt, qml

"I want to draw my visual item object that created in c++ in qml."

- **current state.**

1. I wrote a subclass of QQuickFramebufferObject in C++. 
   and it renders something using its renderer. so I think that is visual item.
2. I register the subclass through qmlRegisterType() for using it in QML.
3. I instanciated the class object in QML and set area to draw something.
4. After the engine loads qml, I find the object which made in QML and put it into a pointer in C++. 
   so that I can add data with the pointer and that updates in QML.
5. It is working well. rendering data on proper area.

- **problem I got.** 
  I am using StackView element for navigation, and when I move to other view and comeback. 
  It seems QML instances in prev view are re-created, so my connections with C++ be invalidated.
- **solution I thought** 
  I am not sure, that is right way or not. Anyway I tried to instanciate the object in C++ not in QML. 
  and register it to QML through setContextProperty(). 
  and set parent, render area for that property, but it is not working the object do not render anything.
- code outline is below

```
// in C++
mCustomWidget = new CustomWidget;
engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("custom_widget", mCustomWidget);

// in QML
Item { // CustomContainer
  id: container
  Component.onCompleted: custom_widget.parent = container
  onXChanged: custom_widget.x = x
  onYChanged: custom_widget.y = y
  onWidthChanged: custom_widget.width = width
  onHeightChanged: custom_widget.height = height
}
```

I expected C++ side has the object so it would be not deleted whether move to other view or not. 
With the pointer in QML side which is context property name, I can see the rendered results if I set its parent and render area.

but, It is something wrong so not working.

Please, let me know the wrong points or other solution. I would be appreciated it. Thank you.

Comment: *"but, It is something wrong so not working."* -- What's not working? You haven't described the problem. Are you getting an error? Is it drawing incorrectly?

Comment: The normal way that C++ objects are drawn through QML is by deriving from QQuickItem.

Comment: according to the [qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#item-ownership): _any item pushed onto a StackView will never be destroyed by the StackView; only items that StackView creates from Components or URLs are destroyed by the StackView_ so that sounds strange that your item is recreated. Anyway, storing a pointer to object when its livetime not in your control sounds strange too. For what do you need this pointer btw?

Comment: @JarManthe the object do not render anything.

Comment: @folibis my meaning is after the object created then I get the pointer and then the object re-created so my pointer is invalidated, which is dangling pointer. and thanks you about stackview, I will check If I am using it rightly.

Comment: @folibis I need the pointer to insert data.

Comment: ok, so you can look for the object at the moment when you need update, every time instead of storing that. Ok do that in a declarative way, provide a model and fetch the data you need from it. Use a signal if you need to inform about this data is ready.